How to search a keyword in github in a subfolder (and it's subfolders) and only for a particular file extension?
I'm trying to search a keyword in a specific search path (together with its subpath), only limiting to specific file extension e.g. .ki

I know I can search for the specific search path using (learn from how to search a particular word or entry inside a sub folder in a repository on github)

https://github.com/myrepo/search?q=mykeyword+path:/mysearchpath


I know I can search for the specific search extention with (learn from How can I search all files ending with the file extension `.feature` on Github?)

https://github.com/myrepo/search?q=mykeyword+path:*.kt



But how can I combine them? I tried the following, all failed

https://github.com/myrepo/search?q=mykeyword+path:/mysearchpath/*.kt (this can't search the subfolder
https://github.com/myrepo/search?q=mykeyword+path:/mysearchpath+path:*.kt


Get what I wanted. Using the extension parameter instead
https://github.com/myrepo/search?q=mykeyword+extension:kt+path:/mysearchpath
Or just add the following in the Github search box
mykeyword path:/mysearchpath extension:kt
Note for just finding the extension

https://github.com/myrepo/search?q=mykeyword+path:*.kt don't work
https://github.com/myrepo/search?q=mykeyword+extension:kt works

